# Running "python setup.py" to install a package as a site-package but python is zipping everything inside egg folder

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, site-packages

Following is the folder structure:
Utility/utils/__init__.py, wrapper, auditory.py
       /setup.py

I have been trying to install utils as site-package in python by running "python setup.py install"

When I go and check the site-package, there is a egg file which has my utils folder and egg-info.
But it should create my utils folder inside site-packages right?
Am I missing something here?

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='utils',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['utils'],
    license='Internal use only',
    zip_safe = False
)
```

Ideally it should place the utils folder inside site-packages and egg-info inside egg file.
so that utils package would be available similar to  and pandas